# How to update data using push to same address - Vue router?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

How to update data using push to same address - Vue router?

I am using push to access the same address after receiving data.

```
methods: {
send(id){
this.$axios.put('/transactions', { id: id }, {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.$store.getters['auth/getToken']}})
  .then(response => {
     this.$router.push('/venda/detalhe/'+id)
  })
  .catch(error => {})
}}
```

Nothing happens.
thank You

Comment: if you are on the page ```/venda/detalhe/<id>``` and after fetching data trying to push router to the same page you will not get any redirection coz you already on this route, you can to use ```window.reload()``` but then your script will featch data again. Probably you also need to provide more extended example of your code for an better answer

Comment: You can put a watch on the route and call the methods that you'd like to call as the watch is triggered. But as @IVI has already stated you'd need to provide a little more information as to what you're trying to attain.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: This is exactly what the @IVI commented on. I want to update the data and load the same page. I have no more code. This is the only method

Comment: Can you not just refresh the component's state (or store if using Vuex)?

Comment: Update with window.reload ()? Would it be good practice?